# Running pytest for python modules inside k8s cluster pod

Tags: kubernetes, pytest

I have a k8s cluster running with one application in one of the pods. The application uses some python modules inside the pod container. I want to execute `pytest` for those python modules after the application runs in that pod. In a docker container env when the same application runs, I can run `pytest` with the command below:

```
docker exec -itw /my_wcd my_application pytest --cov=python_module1 --cov=python_module2 --cov-report=html
```

How can I run `pytest` like that for the application deployed in a microk8s cluster pod environment?

Here's my python file structure inside the pod container:

```
/python/
    module1.py
    module2.py
    __init__.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        test_module1.py
        test_module2.py
        ...
```

Comment: There is a `kubectl exec` command that is analogous to `docker exec`.

Comment: thanks @larsks for the pointer. am able to use kubectl exec call-
`# kubectl exec -it my_test_pod -n test_namespace -- /usr/local/bin/pytest --cov=test_module1 --cov=test_module2 --cov-report=html`

however getting error - 
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /
plugins: cov-3.0.0
collected 0 items / 1 error
/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/coverage/inorout.py:520: CoverageWarning: Module test_module1 was never imported. (module-not-imported)
  self.warn(f"Module {pkg} was never imported.", slug="module-not-imported")
...

Comment: Try removing the `__init__.py` file in your `test` directory.